# Ses mots me volent au (plein) visage

Tags: expressions

Bonjour,

A dit quelque chose à B. B pense :

> Ses mots **me volent au visage**.

Je n'ai pas trouvé beaucoup d'exemples contenant "voler au visage" sur Internet, pourtant j'ai l'impression que j'ai déjà vu cette expression quelque part.

Est-ce que *me volent au visage* est correct ? Est-il possible de dire *me volent au plein visage* ?

Comment: Quel effet ont ces mots sur B ?

Comment: @jlliagre B est très surpris et perplexe, il ne sait pas comment réagir.

Comment: Une autre expression possible : *je pris ces mots  en pleine face*.

Comment: @Damien Oui, merci, c'est d'un style plus relâché.

Comment: Et pourqoui pas "frapper"?

Answer (score 5):

L'expression « voler au visage existe ». On l'emploie au sens propre surtout mais on peut l'employer au sens figuré.

> un vêtement en feu à volé au visage d'une figurante ([site francophone](https://www.christophernolan.fr/filmographie/tenet/tournage/tallinn/) consacré à Christopher Nolan)

> ton inamovible air de détresse qui me vole au visage. (Louise Anne Bouchard, *Vai Piano*,2001)

> Le parfum de sa poudre ambrée qui me vole au visage. ([La Presse](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k546548k#) du 1<sup>er</sup>/01/1892)

« Ces mots me volent au visage » est tout à fait possible et n'a rien de surprenant. Par contre la locution est « en plein » et on l'emploie à la place de « au ». L'emploi de « en plein » donne, à mon avis, un peu plus de vigueur à la portée du coup, donc dans ton exemple, les mots font encore plus mal s'ils arrivent « en plein visage » que s'ils arrivent « au visage ».

Answer (score 1):

Pour rendre *B est très surpris et perplexe, il ne sait pas comment réagir*, je proposerais :

> Ses mots volent à mon visage<sup>1</sup>, je suis interloqué(e).

ou

> Ses mots s'entrechoquent sur mon visage, je suis interloqué(e).

Avec un autre registre, on pourrais aussi écrire:

> Je me prends ses mots en pleine gueule,...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>L'expression habituelle est ***volent à mes oreilles***, mais ***à mon visage*** traduit bien l'effet de collision que l'on souhaite rendre.</sub>

Comment: Merci. Pourquoi _volent à **mon** visage_ est mieux que _**me** volent au visage_ ?

Comment: Je trouve que c'est d'un meilleur style, mais *me volent au visage* est déjà bien.